# Bootstrap3: Responsive Image with fixed Hight should zoom in.

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I want to make a responsive Header for my website. Obviously I used the bootstrap `.img-responsive` class. My Problem with that is, when the screen gets bigger, the height increases too, because  of `height: auto`.
 So on a normal Desktop Screen the picture is too big for me. I´ve seen some websites where the image has a 100 % width, but with a fixed hight. If the width is changed the picture zooms in or pans around. Here is an [example](http://2017.dockercon.com) of what I mean.
I searched for resource on that online but found nothing. Can anybody of you guys help me out?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post the code you've tried so far? It should be a matter of setting a min-height.

Comment: What you want to do is set the image as the `background-image` of the div. Set the height of the div to whatever you want, width 100% and then add a `background-image` with `background-size:cover;`

Comment: more like a `max-width` problem to me, set a `max-width` to the img.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on my comment above, if you want the image to scale depending on the screen size while maintaining the same height, use the `background-image` property on an element with a defined height:

```css
.hero {
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/1000/450/nature');
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

If you're not happy with where the image is cropping, you can use `background-position` to adjust it:

```css
.hero {
  width:100%;
  height:300px;
  background-image:url('https://placeimg.com/1000/450/nature');
  background-position:center center;
  background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero"></div>
```

Comment: With this fixed height it can't be reponsive

Comment: @blecaf sure it can, it is in my example. If the OP wants the height to be responsive as well, they just need to define different heights for the various breakpoints.

Comment: Please explain the downvote, my answer does exactly what the OP is asking for(even using the same method as the example they provided).

Comment: I didn't down vote you. I just commented. Giving a height to an image does not do well with responsiveness. min-height and max-height works better.

Comment: `min-height` and `max-height` won't work for this solution as there is no content in the div to give the element a height. My answer uses the same solution that's being used in the example provided by the OP.